# ¿Cómo puedo transformar esta data en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, excel

se me encargó la tarea de pasar esta información de un Excel a una Base de Datos SQL Server (La imagen está con datos demo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno, esa información se sube tal y como está al SQL Server. y es necesario transformarlo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sería de mucha utilidad una pista de como conseguir eso(la idea no es modificar la tabla, si no pasarlo a otra tabla).

Comment: ¿En dónde está tu problema? ¿En como subir un tabla de un Excel a la BD o en como transformar un formato "apaisado"  a un "vertical"?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres. ¿Sabes SQL? Lo digo por que si no sabes nada de SQL lo tienes difícil.  Tendrías primero que crear las diferentes tablas con sus relaciones lo que viene a ser un diagrama aunque sea básico (yo ahí con esos datos demos veo al menos 5 tablas), luego te creas las tablas, y ya si eso utilizas una vista o una consulta. Creo que no te vale solo con una tabla por que se ve que hay diferentes relaciones en tu excel. Luego si estas trabajando con un gestor de bases de datos SQL pues sería muy fácil en un nivel básico:

Para crear tablas:
CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla ( 
columna tipo_dato [RESTRICCIONES]
[mas columnas]
[restricciones a nivel de tabla] );

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Para insertar datos:
INSERT INTO tabla (columnas[mas columnas]) VALUES (datos[mas datos]);

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Luego puedes hacer la consulta con un SELECT o crear una vista con CREATE VIEW.

En w3c encontrarás la información que necesitas, pero vamos si no sabes de SQL lo veo difícil, yo llevo 4 meses estudiando SQL y aún estoy empezando.